# MongoDB get the records even when partial match is false

Tags: mongodb

agency Table has a lot of agencies

each agency can have several users, if they are users.type: "agent"

This all works great, but....

If the agency has no users.type: "agent", then I also dont get the agency

I want to get all agency weather they got users or not.

If I remove this line

```
// { $match: { 'users.type': 'agent' } },
```

then I get all agencies with all users no matter what type they are so thats bad

If I insert the line, I get all agencies with agent type users, but I do **not** get all agencies who have **no users**.

I wish there was a way to put the `{ $match: { 'users.type': 'agent' } },` inside the users `$lookup`

Anyone got a workaround that can help here?

```
agencyTable.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "agency", 
            as: "users"     
        }   
    },
    { $unwind:  { path: "$users", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }, 

    // { $match: { 'users.type': 'agent' } }, 

    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "phone": { "$first": "$phone" },
            "website": { "$first": "$website" },
            "address": { "$first": "$address" },
            "googlemaps": { "$first": "$googlemaps" },
            "rating": { "$first": "$rating" },
            "activityDate": { "$first": "$activityDate" },
            "users": { "$push": "$users" }
        }
    },  
    {
        $addFields: {
            "users": {
                "$map": {
                "input":"$users",
                "as":"usr",
                "in":{
                    "userID":"$$usr._id",
                    "userName":"$$usr.name",
                    "userPhone":"$$usr.phone"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id" : 1,
            "phone" : 1,
            "website" : 1,
            "address" : 1,
            "googlemaps" : 1,
            "rating" : 1,
            "activityDate" : 1,
            "users" : 1
        }
    }
])
```

Hmmm... could I do the `$match: { 'users.type': 'agent'` down in the $`addfields`?  Is that possible?

```
  db.agency.aggregate([ { '$match': {} }, { '$sort': { activityDate: 1 } }, 

  { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'agency', as: 'users' } }, 
  { '$unwind': { path: '$users', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }, 

  { '$match': {
    '$or': [ 
        { 'users.type': 'agent' }, 
        { 'users': { '$exists': false } } 
        ]
    } }

])
```

This one is not working (unfortunately) because there are no 'agent' type users.
There are lots of 'tenant' type uses, so if I replace agent with tenant it works great.

If I keep it I get no results at all.  Hmmmm.....
I dont understand - in my mind this should work!

Comment: Your query will give you all agencies that have user type 'agent' or that are not related to users at all.. the result is empty means all your agencies are related to users and you don't have agencies with user type 'agen'  - commented from mobile device

Comment: Exactly!!! :)  So when they were type "tenant" and still related to agency, thats when it failed.  Anyway I fixed that already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you want to get users of type "agent" and users with no agency.

Try changing your match query to this:

```
 { 
         $match: { 
                    $or: [

                            {
                                'users.type': 'agent'
                            },
                            {
                                "users": {$exists: false }
                            },

                        ]
             } 


      },
```

Comment: such a nice simple solution - and to me this should work - but somehow it does not, its like it ignores the $exists:false  - let me try and post it in the question

Comment: Your code works as it should - found out the problem was something else :-)